# Typesafe onChange for React JS FormControl events

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have a function that handles a changing text field:

```
private handleNameChange(e: React.FormEvent<FormControl>) {
    const name = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ name });
    this.props.editGroupName(name);
}
```

This is wired up to the onChange of a FormControl:

```
<FormControl type='text' placeholder='Name' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
```

However, this is mistyped, according to TypeScript:

```
TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

I've also tried using `currentTarget`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to replace `e: React.FormEvent<FormControl>` with `e: React.FormEvent<FormControlProps>`.

Comment: I've found the solution here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16208